# How can i show the hint of an EditText item even if typing

Tags: android, android-edittext, type-hinting

While i starts typing on editText box the hint is getting disappear. I want to show the hint all the time, the hint may go a little up when typing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [TextInputLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html). It supports both floating hint and error.

Example [here](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/becoming-material-with-android-design-support-library/).